# Non-glassy amorphous solids

Tags: material-science, states-of-matter, amorphous-solids, glass

According to Wikipedia:

- A [**glass**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass) is any "solid that possesses a non-crystalline (that is, amorphous) structure at the atomic scale and that exhibits a glass transition when heated towards the liquid state".
- A [**glass transition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_transition) is "the reversible transition in amorphous materials (or in amorphous regions within semicrystalline materials) from a hard and relatively brittle 'glassy' state into a viscous or rubbery state as the temperature is increased."

It seems like most familiar non-crystalline solids (e.g. household plastics, [cheese](http://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/50089)) become more ductile and less brittle when heated.  Does this mean these are all considered glasses?  What is an example of an amorphous solid that is *not* a glass?

Comment: Plastics often are partially crystalline. BTW I think I don't wanna imagine "ductile" cheese. And no it isn't a glass, even not exactly a *solid*.

Answer (score -2):

Plastics are made if polymers, which are chains of molecules, therefore i don't think we can call it a glass even though some of them are amorphous, because they are ordered at the atomic scale.

Comment: Polymers are generally speaking either semicrystalline with glassy amorphous regions or completely amorphous below their glass transition temerature. So yes, it is completely normal to call them glasses.

Comment: Yes you convinced me, you are absolutely right.